# How to get all Spring bean names in a jar file?

Tags: java, spring, jar

I have a jar file in which some Spring beans are defined. My question is given the `InputStream` object of this jar file, how to get all Spring bean names from it? Or is there any Spring official api with the `InputStream` as parameter to get the instance of  `ApplicationContext`? If the answer is yes, then I can use `ApplicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()` to get the bean name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whar do you mean by InputStream to a .jar file? Do you have one in a mechanism of some sort? Or from plain file/directory reading?...

Comment: This jar file is uploaded from web page and the `InputStream` object is got from the parameter object of `MultipartFile` type in the handler method of spring controller class.

Comment: getBeanDefinitionNames returns  the names of all beans defined in this factory. The answer i wrote for two scenarios, will also give the same output aka bean definition names.. please check. @walsh

Comment: Have a look at org.xeustechnologies.jcl.JarClassLoader. The methods _add_ and _getLoadedClasses_ could be handy. You'll have to look for Spring-Annotations in the classes.

Comment: @Turo I use xml-style configuration.:(  Currently, I want to find a Spring official api to solve this problem.

Comment: did you solved this issue? @walsh

Comment: @TahirHussainMir No. I'm still finding a better solution. It will be solved in next month.

Answer (score 0):

I can Add the answer, which once helped me in the same case.

You can also use [JarInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html#getNextJarEntry()) [check the linked documentyation]

Here is the example, I hope it may help You.

```
try {
           File file = new File("myJar.jar");
           FileInputStream fInput = new FileInputStream(file);
           JarInputStream jInput = new JarInputStream(fInput);
           //This class is used to represent a JAR file entry.
           JarEntry je;
           while((je=jInput.getNextJarEntry())!=null){
                 //gives fully qualified name of classes inside jar
                 System.out.println(je.getName());
           }
           jInput.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

In case of **InputStream**:

```
void someMethodName(InputStream jarFile) {
JarInputStream jarInputStream = null;
try {
    jarInputStream = new JarInputStream(jarFile);
    JarEntry je;
    while((je=jarInputStream.getNextJarEntry())!=null){
                 //gives fully qualified name of classes inside jar
                 System.out.println(je.getName());
    }catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

Don't know, whether it will help or not, but i thought i had done this few times and why not share it with You. If it helped please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But sorry for my bad description.  What I need is to get all spring bean information defined in the jar file not the filename in the jar file. Thanks again!

Comment: i edited my answer. Please check for InputStream. And what do You mean by all spring bean information??? @walsh

Comment: I use Spring framework and defined some bean in that file.

Comment: getBeanDefinitionNames returns the names of all beans defined in this factory. The answer i wrote for two scenarios, will also give the same output aka bean definition names.. please check. @walsh

Answer (score 0):

you can know all the beans declared in a specific jar, to do that you must pass the spring beans configuration file name as defined in jar/war to ApplicationContext. You can pass as many config files as you want by passing configuration file names in double-quotes &  comma separated like this:

```
    ApplicationContext appCon = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("parentConfig.xml","springConfig.xml");
```

Considering the spring configuration file "springConfig.xml" is defined inside a jar/war & "parentConfig.xml" file is actual spring configuration file defined in the current project.

You are right, you can get all the beans declared using getBeanDefinitionNames()

```
List<String> beansList = Arrays.asList(appCon.getBeanDefinitionNames());

beansList.forEach(bean -> System.out.println(bean));
```

The above statements will print all the beans defined in jar/war file & as well as  beans declared in current project spring configuration file("parentConfig.xml").